# Forge Viewer Shading problem with DWF files

Tags: autodesk-forge

My Forge Viewer app is using dataViz extension for shading of rooms. This works perfectly with Revit files. However, with DWF files, color does not set correctly. Instead, white-pattern show up.
[image]

Space boundaries are correctly identified.

Anyone knows a way to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot
Bandu

Comment: Further, this URN is picked from ACC Docs - after uploading DWF model to ACC and having it translate it.

Comment: Our apologies for the late response. Our support case queue has a long backlog, but there are fewer resources to handle cases due to the coming APS DevCon. Therefore, I see your inquiry just now.
 
Well... this is a strange issue. I can reproduce that on my side with your test model. But sorry, I run out of my idea as well. I cannot tell what caused this issue. So, I'm checking with our engineering team. Will get back once they reply. While waiting for their response, I would suggest you use known, supported & tested formats like RVT, IFC, and NWC/NWD instead as a workaround.